# How to get url parameters in grails spring security custom UserDetailsServices class?

Tags: grails, authentication, spring-security, url-mapping

I have two login pages, one for user and other for admin. In order to know who is trying to login, I think of having a url pattern like `/app/admin/login` and `/app/user/login`. I cannot change by subdomain. This is a grails application which uses spring security. So by default all the login requests are sent to `/j_spring_security_check` url. What should I do in order to change the login submission url from `/j_spring_security_check` to `/app/$context/login` where $context can be user or admin?

Another problem I face is, how to get the request params my custom UserDetailsServices class? The `params` is not available in that class, so I cannot write `params.context` like we do in Filters class.

Any insight into this would be highly helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [This](http://mark.koli.ch/2010/07/spring-3-and-spring-security-setting-your-own-custom-j-spring-security-check-filter-processes-url.html) post might help with the j_spring_security question.
   The solution is not for Grails directly, but I have seen that Grails allows you to customize Spring any way you like.
2. For the service layer question regarding params: 
   params is an implicit HttpRequest.parameters object for Controller. One should never try to expect any Http awareness in the service layer.

So its  a good thing we can't reference it in the service layer. My advice would be to pass it as an argument to the service class method.

Comment: its working for me. It basically talks about this : http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.html